# How to organise multi package flutter project and use it as dependency

Tags: module, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I would like to organise a flutter project into a multi-package one with following requirements:

- use one repository for this project
- able for developers to work on the packages in this repository locally
- make the packages accessible as dependencies from other projects outside of this repository

The file setup for the repository I have now is:

```
.
├── app_base
│   ├── ...
│   └── pubspec.yaml
├── feature
│   ├── ...
│   └── pubspec.yaml
└── README.md
```

I tried using path dependencies like this in `app_base/pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: app_base

dependencies:
  feature:
    path: ../feature
```

and it works for local development but if I try to use `app_base` in a completely different project and not use paths but a git dependency:

```
name: actual_app

dependencies:
  app_base:
    git:
      url: ssh://address.to/the_repo.git
      path: app_base
      ref: deadbaca
```

it cannot resolve the transitive `feature` dependency:

```
Running "flutter packages get" in actual_app...            
Error on line 21, column 11: Invalid description: "../feature" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
    path: ../feature
          ^^^^^^^^^^

pub get failed (65)
Process finished with exit code 65
```

Is there a way to make it work for both local development and used as a git dependency from other project?

Answer (score 1):

Just use Git dependencies for both scenarios (locally and for other projects).

If you think this is cumbersome during local development, use path dependencies locally and change it back to Git before committing.